# Count several post tags

Tags: posts, tags, count

This maybe should be posted on a php forum, but since it's WordPress related, I'm giving it a try here..

With this code, I'll get the total count of posts work a certain tag;

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', lizard, post_tag);
echo $term->count;
```

How do I write if I would like to know how many posts there are in 10 different tags together?

I guess some kind of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I write if I would like to know how many posts there are in 10
>   different tags together?

If you mean the combined total number of posts, i.e. the sum of the `count` value of each term, then:

1. Yes, you can put the slug list in an array and loop through the items to manually sum the grand total:

   ```php
   $term_slugs = [ 'slug', 'slug-2', 'etc' ];
   $post_count = 0;

   foreach ( $term_slugs as $slug ) {
       $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, 'post_tag' );
       $post_count += $term->count;

       // This is just for testing.
       echo $term->name . ': ' . $term->count . '<br>';
   }

   echo 'Grand total posts: ' . $post_count;
   ```
2. Or if all you need is just the grand total, then you can simply use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) or [`get_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_tags/) (which uses `get_terms()` btw) *with [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/)* without having to do a `foreach` loop:

   ```php
   $term_slugs = [ 'slug', 'slug-2', 'etc' ];
   $terms = get_terms( [
       'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
       'slug'     => $term_slugs,
   ] );
   /* Or with get_tags():
   $terms = get_tags( [ 'slug' => $term_slugs ] );
   */

   $post_count = array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'count' ) );
   echo 'Grand total posts: ' . $post_count;
   ```